# raising my existing concrete floor 20cm up

Tags: concrete, flooring

How can I raise my existing concrete floor by 20cm up? can I directly add aggregates and sand and finish with concrete, or do I have to chip first the existing floor?

Answer (score 1):

No, The existing slab is an excellent base.  Fill it with the least expensive aggregate you can buy and pour your new slab.  Good Luck and happy finishing.

Comment: 20 cm is nearly 8 inches. that's a lot of weight in concrete. does it need to be concrete?

Comment: yes it should be concrete. will there be a possibility that the existing slab on grid may crashed down? .

Comment: No Chance. I'm assuming the original slab is sitting on the earth.

Comment: yes. the original slab is sitting on earth.